# can't find mapping of "android.permission.INTERNET" permission to famous methods which should use it

Tags: android, permissions

I was trying to evaluate effective permissions usage of an apk using [axplorer](http://axplorer.org/) [mapping files](https://github.com/reddr/axplorer/tree/master/permissions).
During evaluation I obtained an effective use of the *android.permission.INTERNET* permission equal to 0.

This sounds pretty weird considering that this is maybe the most **USED** permission of all ([android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting) just tells an apk must declare this permission "In order to perform network operation"...)

This weird result depends on the fact that in axplorer mapping files there aren't mappings of famous "internet using" methods (*java.net.HttpURLConnection*, *java.net.HttpsUrlConnection*, *java.net.Socket* etc...) with *android.permission.INTERNET* permission.

I also knew that axplorer project replaced [pscout](https://security.csl.toronto.edu/pscout/) project, so I took a look at pscout's [mapping files](https://security.csl.toronto.edu/pscout/datasets/) either and found that in pscout's mapping files of android versions from *Jelly Bean* to *Froyo* there actually **ARE** mappings of *java.net.HttpURLConnection*, *java.net.Socket* etc.. methods with the permission, but for *4.11-5.11* android version, there is no mapping with these methods, and the mapping files become very similar to axplorer mapping files of android more recent versions.

Someone can help me find out why I'm seeing this strange case in permissions mappings?

I need to evaluate permissions effectively usage, but a "zero usage" of *android.permission.INTERNET* has really to be false... Someone can help me with that? Maybe there's something wrong in my idea?

Comment: Leaving as just a comment, since this isn't complete, but might provide some ideas for research: INTERNET permission is tied to `inet` GID, which is handled in a special way in Android Linux Kernel.

Comment: Thanky you for answering anyway: every help is appreciated :).
Could you give me some documentation about INTERNET permission tying with `inet` GID?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/etc/platform.xml